# App Crahes in different devices

Tags: android, crash

So, My app crashes on 3 other devices but it works fine on the device I have been using since the beginning of the development process. When I checked the LogCat, I got this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.......MainActivity}:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

java.lang.String
 com.parse.ParseUser.getUsername() on a null object reference
```

I assume it is because of this code:

```
    //get current user
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    //get current user username and turn it to string
    final String currentUserUsername = currentUser.getUsername();

    //identify if current user is logged in
    if (currentUser != null) {
        // bring user to homepage and do stuff with the user
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("My");
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        query.whereEqualTo("user", currentUserUsername);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> personObject, ParseException e) {
                if(e == null){
                    //success
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome Back, " + currentUserUsername + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    mPerson = peopleObject;

                    MyPeopleAdapter adapter = new MyPeopleAdapter(getListView().getContext(), mPerson);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                } else {
                    //problem
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is a problem. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        // show the signup or login screen
        Intent SignIn = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
        startActivity(SignIn);
    }
```

But, how can this be a problem? I have been logging in and out of the app with the first device over and over again without any problem. And why is it causing problem with the other devices?

**UPDATE:**

I just found out if I remove the code, the app works just fine. But it doesn't work when I have the code.

Comment: This article talks about a possible race condition which might explain why it works on one device but not others.  Not sure if it is relevant, but perhaps it will help.     https://www.parse.com/questions/android-getcurrentuser-returns-null-sometimes-after-logging-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the crash by remove the problematic line from outside the Null checking and insert it to the if loop::

```
//identify if current user is logged in
if (currentUser != null) {
    //get current user username and turn it to string
    final String currentUserUsername = currentUser.getUsername(); //this line was outside earlier
   //rest of code
}
```

Comment: Remove the final string? Or remove everything? Can you explain?

Comment: It is actually very simple: in first line you call ParseUser.getCurrentUser(), but when you invoke getUsername() on the currentUser you ignore the possibility that getCurrentUser() can return null, so you must first to check if currentUser  not empty.