# NullPointerException on bigger screen devices

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

When I run my app on Motorola Nexus 6 , I get NullPointerException.Problem is with one TextView and setting text on same.I saw some solutions online, but none of them worked for me.I guess problem is with JVM on different smartphones, or with lifecycle of my fragment which is nested inside activity.

Everything is working fine on smaller devices.

Log bellow:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com..data.models.entity.Email.getUsername()' on a null object reference
                                                     at com..presenter.view.fragment.ForgotPasswordFragmentComplete.onStart(ForgotPasswordFragmentComplete.java:84)
```

Here is my Fragment:

```
 @Bind(R.id.button_resend_email)
    AppCompatButton resendEmail;
    @Bind(R.id.resend_user_email)AutoResizeTextView resendEmailTxt;

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DaggerForgotPasswordCompletedComponent.builder()
                .applicationComponent(
                        ((AndroidApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getApplicationComponent())
                .forgotPasswordCompletedModule(new ForgotPasswordCompletedModule())
                .build()
                .inject(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        realm = getRealm();
        RealmQuery<Email> query1 = realm.where(Email.class);
        Email result1 = query1.findFirst();

        resendEmailTxt = (AutoResizeTextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.resend_user_email) ;

        this.resendEmailTxt.setText(result1.getUsername());

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();


    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forgot_password_fragment_complete, container, false);


    }


    @Override
    protected int getFragmentLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.fragment_forgot_password_fragment_complete;
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense for this to be screen related. What does getRealm() look like?

Comment: On Samsung Galaxy S4, everything is working fine. It is just getting Realm instance and initialization.

Answer (score 1):

If you get `nullPointerException` it probably means your `result1` variable has not been assigned a value. That implies that your `query1.findFirst()` may be returning nothing at all.

Comment: query1,findFirst is returning right thing, already check that with Log.And it is working fine on galaxy s4.

Comment: @AnonimoAnonimus The exception in your question says otherwise.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366061/app-crahes-in-different-devices) link, it seems to be similar to your problem.

Comment: Yes, Its seems that it because of  Email result1 = query1.findFirst(); return null

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your code from `onStart()` to `onResume()`.